# How to play sound files simultaneously?

Tags: c#, sharpdx

After referencing SharpDX, I'm not sure how to proceed to play multiple files from my computer at the same time.

```
using SharpDX;
using SharpDX.DirectSound;
using SharpDX.Multimedia;
using SharpDX.XAudio2;


var xaudio2 = new XAudio2();
var masteringVoice = new MasteringVoice(xaudio2);

var stream = new SoundStream(File.OpenRead(fileAddress.wav));
var waveFormat = stream.Format;

var Secondxaudio2 = new XAudio2();
var SecondmasteringVoice = new MasteringVoice(xaudio2);

var Secondstream = new SoundStream(File.OpenRead(fileAddress.wav));
var SecondwaveFormat = stream.Format;
```

**Play simultaneously**

Comment: Heads up: Visual Studio is the application with which you author your code, C# is not Visual Studio, .NET is not Visual Studio, etc. Visual Studio plays no part in executing your code.

Comment: The Sharpdx git repo has a plethora of samples on how to play samples, including how to set up your voice channels to play multiple samples.  Please refer to https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX

Comment: You don't have to do your audio with SharpDx.. I prefer the NAudio library, adding sounds to its pipeline is easy, I've used it in a SharpDx rollercoaster simulator to play wave recording and Mp4 together. https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=csharp+naudio